# Inserting date in database with hour and minutes

Tags: sql, oracle11g

This is the method i use to insert a date into the database:

```
public void insertLog(Connection con, UserLogs userLogs) throws SQLException{
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    ResultSet rs= null;
    String SQL = "insert into logs values(?,to_date(sysdate,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'))";

    try {
        pstmt = con.prepareStatement(SQL);
        pstmt.setInt(1, userLogs.getUserId());
        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }finally{
        if(rs!=null){
            rs.close();
        }
        if(pstmt!=null){
            pstmt.close();
        } 
    }
}
```

Now there is a problem... it does successfully insert it but when i do an Select * from logs the hour and minutes appear as 00:00 (using oracle) so my guess is that i have to alter session with this format:

```
alter session set nls_date_format='DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI';
```

in order for the display to work properly. How can i send this sql followed by an insert in the same executeQuery?

Comment: `to_date(sysdate, ...)` is totally useless. `sysdate` is already a `date` there is no need to convert it to one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the insert statement you are using

```
SELECT to_date(sysdate,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI') FROM dual;
```

returns

```
9/24/0014
```

if you do

```
SELECT sysdate FROM dual;
```

it will return

```
9/24/2014 14:56:54
```

There is no need to do the to_date on sysdate as it already includes the full date and time.

Comment: da f*** that was dumb from my part, misunderstood concept lol